# Managing a smart mailing groups (un)subscriptions

Tags: smartgroups, mailing, administer

According to
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/organising-your-data/smart-groups/

> Smart groups respect people's subscription preferences. If people
>   unsubscribe from the newsletter, they will be removed from the smart
>   group.

Are there ways to

- see who unsubscribed from smart groups
- manually unsubscribe members as an admin

Answer (score 2):

On the manage group screen (civicrm/group?reset=1) click on contacts next to the group in question. There you should be able to search for added pending and removed contacts for this particular group.

Comment: That sounds good. But in reality, searching there for 'added','removed' or 'pending' in a smart group all show the same results. Is that a bug ?

Comment: If you have added them all via the Backend, that makes sense if no one has unsubscribed. Pending is only used if someone signed up online but thit not confirm the subscription.

Comment: It's a smart group. I haven't added anyone, the system itself adds and removes people according to the given 'smart' definition. People did unsubscribe, but I can't see who have, and I have no way of manually unsubscribing them afaik.

Comment: Those that are unsubscribed should have the status removed. If that's not working, I guess it could be a bug. PS You can still manually add contacts to a smart group even if they don't meet the smart group's criteria.

Comment: OK - a bug then. Notice I how searching for 'added' yields exactly the same results as searching for 'removed', eg the same 1000 contacts that are added are also removed and pending all at the same time.

Comment: Did you want to add a screenshot? Anyway it sounds like a bug or local problem, I am sure this was working in 4.6 for me before...